# Passing a Model between View Controllers

Tags: arrays, swift, model, parameter-passing, viewcontroller

I am struggling to pass a model of data from one controller to the next. I am sure I am just missing something very simple but hoping I can get some help.

Below I create the code to select all the data from the row that was selected:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        print(indexPath.row)
        
        let passingData = arrivals[indexPath.row]
        print(passingData)
        let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FlightInfoVC") as! FlightInfoViewController
        controller.flightDataPassedIn = passingData
        //Code incomplete - Will add execution to show VC
        
    }
```

That print statement is reflected below:
[image: console]

Now where I am struggling is to get that data to go to my next view controller. Setting the array of data in my new VC doesn't seem to work because it is expecting a type of 'FlightModel' but I cannot seem to figure out how to declare that. I have tried this but I `cannot convert type [Any] to 'FlightModel'`

`var flightDataPassedIn: FlightModel = []`

Appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: You are mixing Segue & Manual creations of `UIViewConntroller` from a Storyboard. Choose one method or the other, but don't do both.

Comment: Very good point - I forgot i left that last line

Comment: It's still unclear. Did you have a segue at first? If yes, keep using the segue. If not, then you created the ViewController `let controller = ...`, but never showed it.

Comment: I know I have never created that action yet - I know how to write that part of the code to transition the view - What I care about is the passage of data

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is that you're trying to initialize `flightDataPassedIn` with a value of `[]`, which is of incompatible type `[Any]`.

If you're okay with the `flightDataPassedIn` property on `FlightInfoViewController` being optional, that might be the most straightforward solution. It would automatically be initialized to `nil`, so would not require you to set an initial value - just declare it like this:

`var flightDataPassedIn: FlightModel?`

If you don't want it to be optional, initialize it to a default value of type `FlightModel` (add an initializer to `FlightModel` if necessary) and overwrite it with `passingData` from the parent ViewController.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That cleared the errors but now all im getting is nil values since setting everything optional... How does the data get assigned?

First VC:
`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let dataToPass = arrivals[indexPath.row] 
        let destinationVC = FlightInfoViewController()
        destinationVC.flightDataPassedIn = dataToPass
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "TrackingToInfo", sender: self)
    }`

Comment: Second VC

`var flightDataPassedIn : FlightModel?`

Then in the ViewDidLoad

`print(flightDataPassedIn)`

Comment: I haven't used segues in years so I could be wrong, but it doesn't look like the segue ever references the specific instance of `FlightInfoViewController` you created. Have you tried using `present(destinationVC, animated: true)` instead of `performSegue(withIdentifier: "TrackingToInfo", sender: self)`?

Comment: Just figured it out - had to use the prepare for segue function

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was not passing the data via the main required function that everyone uses `Prepare for segue`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "TrackingToInfo" {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? FlightInfoViewController {
                destinationVC.flightDataPassedIn = readyToPass
            }
        }
    }
```

Within the tableview I had to set the data to a var in my currentVC of type `FlightModel?` then the data passed